# why isn't this jquery adding the right values to my db

Tags: jquery

OK so i have the below code. It is doing everything it should except updating the right db query. For example if I click on the WEST button it still adds 1 to ucord2 and takes 1 from ucord1. I want each one of these to run separately depending on the button clicked.

```
<?///////////////////////////NORTH BELOW///////////////////////////////////?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function north() {
<?$north = 1;
$db->query( "UPDATE users SET uCord2=uCord2+$north WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );?>
    $.get("conquest.php");
    return false;
}
</script>
<a href="conquest.php" onclick="north();">NORTH</a>
<?//////////////////////////WEST BELOW///////////////////////////////////////////?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function west() {
<?$west = 1;
$db->query( "UPDATE users SET uCord1=uCord1-$west WHERE uID='" . $user['uID'] . "'" );?>
    $.get("conquest.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="conquest.php" onclick="west();">WEST</a>
```

Comment: Your queries will be executed at the time the page is rendered. They won't be executed when you click a link. Be aware of the separation between Javascript and PHP

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it so my querys are rendered on a link click?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change

```
uCord1=uCord1-$west
```

to

```
uCord1=uCord1+$west
```

in your west SQL query?

Hard to see exactly what you're attempting to do only seeing this snippet.

Comment: im just trying to add it to the database then it reload the page showing the new results. The reason for the -$west is to take away 1 from cord1.